Inrush current limiter circuit with MOSFET
I am researching the inrush current limiter topology. I understand what is done with NTC or resistor. However, I am a little confused about the circuits made with active components such as MOSFET, and I would be very happy if someone could explain it using the circuit you see in the picture or a simple circuit if you have it.


Welcome! Your circuit doesn’t show any MOSFET. Do you have DC input?

@winny
I know it is not a MOSFET because I have difficulty understanding the circuits made with MOSFET, so I wanted to ask.

Find one which you believe suits your needs, simulate it and we’ll help you from there. Do you have AC or DC input?

@winny I have DC input.

Just use this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/plugins/schematics?image=https%3a%2f%2fi.sstatic.net%2fcyFgk.png

@Antonio51 Well, in order to understand the state of this circuit without inrush protection, would it be possible if the 10mF and load resistor were left with a source?

Yes. You can dismiss all except the load resistor and 10 mF. You should then see an impressive "spike" current power source.

Technically, inrush current is the current through D1 in your schematic. Initially those capacitors are discharged, and represent a near-short-circuit to ground, which causes D1 current to start so high (that's the "inrush"), but current is limited by the diode's own resistance, to a maximum of 5A or so in this instance. It would be a lot, lot more if D1 were not present to limit it, and if voltage source V1 were ideal. In practice, source impedance (of V1), wiring resistance, and capacitor ESR would also put a cap on inrush current.
After the capacitors have charged to the same voltage as V1 (or slightly less, due to D1's "drop" of 0.3V or so), current falls quite suddenly, because there's no longer any potential difference between V1 and capacitor voltage to cause a current to flow.
Current still does flow, however, but now it's exclusively through the load, explaining why current eventually falls to:
$$ I_{D1} = \frac{V_1 - V_{D1}}{R_1} = \frac{12V - 0.3V}{20\Omega} = 0.59A $$
The goal of inrush current suppression is to introduce a resistance in that path of current from V1, significant compared to wiring resistance and capacitor ESR, to put a cap on the maximum current that can flow. The resistance is ephemeral, though, and should disappear once the capacitors have fully charged.
There are two methods I can think of, that use a MOSFET as that resistance. The first method relies purely on timing, to start with a high resistance, and slowly decrease it to zero.
This uses a P-channel MOSFET whose \$V_{GS}\$ is prevented from instantly increasing to maximum, using an RC delay:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The top circuit is without any attempt to mitigate inrush current. RS1 represents source and wiring impedance, which limits current to some extent, but not by much, as shown in blue here:

The lower circuit uses R1 and C1 to slow the fall of gate potential \$V_G\$. The MOSFET begins to switch on when \$V_{GS}=V_G-V_S=V_{GS(TH)}=-4V\$, but is only fully switched on at about \$V_{GS}=-6V\$. It takes a few milliseconds to traverse that region of \$V_{GS}\$, during which the MOSFET's \$R_{DS}\$ is significant enough to throttle current, as shown in orange. Eventually, though, \$V_{GS}=-12V\$, where \$R_{DS}\$ is at its minimum.
This design can be modified slightly to permit current flow even before the MOSFET switches on, by providing a resistive route around the MOSFET:

simulate this circuit
A controlled amount of current begins to flow as soon as power is applied, but at some point the MOSFET switches on (slowly), taking over the role of current throttling, until it eventually become a near short-circuit:

Another technique is to simply limit current to some maximum, which should of course be somewhat greater than the load's requirements. This is easily achieved using an additional BJT, but the MOSFET is still employed in a role similar to above:

simulate this circuit
Resistor R1 is chosen to develop 0.7V or so when maximum current is passing. To limit current to about 10A:
$$ R_1 \approx \frac{0.7V}{10A} \approx 70m\Omega $$
When the voltage across R1 reaches 0.7V, Q1 switches on, raising gate potential \$V_G\$, and switching off MOSFET M1. The system enters an equilibrium where current is unable to rise any further since doing so would further throttle that very same current.
The result is that until the capacitors are charged, current can never exceed about 10A:

It's interesting to watch output voltage \$V_{OUT}\$ during the charging phase. Since output current is now constant for a while, capacitor voltage rise is initially very linear (not exponential):

In all these examples, power dissipation in the MOSFET is a big concern. For a few milliseconds current through it, and voltage across it, are significant, causing the device to heat up fast, so it's important to crunch the numbers properly, to avoid exceeding its tolerances.

A big problem with an inrush limiter that act as static current sources is that it will act like a bad fuse would if there's ever an overload on the output. Literally like a bad fuse: the mosfet will self-destruct, and may fail shorted or open depending on luck if load is ever short-circuited. To be practical, there needs to be either an actual time-lag fuse to limit the load current to below the inrush value, or the mosfet needs thermal protection and a large SOA (electronic-fuse-like), or the circuit should only limit current for a short duration and then turn hard-on.

There is no MOSFET in your circuit.  The point of MOSFETs in inrush circuits is to bypass the inrush current limiter as such once the inrush is over.  The limiting devices (PTC or similar) will also limit operating current and use up energy.  A MOSFET can tunnel large currents without significant voltage drop.

I know there is no MOSFET. I don't understand inrush current limiter with MOSFET circuits. The reason I am here. The above circuit is just to show the inrush current phenomenon.
